# Rewrite expression eliminating roots in denominator

Tags: radicals, rationalising-denominator

I need help with the following problem:

Rewrite the following expression so that the denominator contains no root expression and the fraction has been shortened as far as possible.

[image: Expression]

I have tried to express it as

[image]

But I'm not sure how to continue from there.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance. Also, please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post.

Comment: Tried to add my understanding so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we have a power of a power we can multiply the exponents, this is to say that for three numbers $a, m, n$ it is true that
$$ (a^m)^n = a^{mn}$$.

Notice that $8 = 2^3$ and $64 = 4^3$. We can simplify this a bit by

$$
    y = \frac{\sqrt[3]{x} + \sqrt[3]{8}}{\sqrt[3]{64} - \sqrt[3]{8x} + \sqrt[3]{x^2}} =
    \frac{\sqrt[3]{x} + \sqrt[3]{2^3}}{\sqrt[3]{4^3} - \sqrt[3]{2^3 \cdot x} + \sqrt[3]{x^2}} =
    \frac{\sqrt[3]{x} + 2}{4 - 2 \sqrt[3]{x} + \sqrt[3]{x^2}}
$$

And we can factor a sum of two cubes as

$$
    a^3 + b^3 = (a+b)(a^2 - ab + b^2)
$$
(Please  verify this in your own.) It is a little tricky to notice at first, but it is what you have in the bottom of the fraction. It may be easier to see if we set $u = \sqrt[3]{x}$

$$
y = \frac{u + 2}{4 - 2u + u^2} =
    \frac{u + 2}{u^2 - 2u + 4} =
    \frac{u + 2}{u^2 - 2u + 2^2}
$$

Now, multiply both sides by $\frac{u+2}{u+2}=1$ (we can do this becouse multiply by 1 does nothing), and get

$$
y = \frac{(u + 2)(u + 2)}{(u + 2)(u^2 - 2u + 2^2)}
  = \frac{u^2 + 4u + 4}{u^3 + 2^3} 
  = \frac{u^2 + 4u + 4}{u^3 + 8} 
$$

And just substitute that $u = \sqrt[3]{x}$, and we have

$$
y = \frac{(\sqrt[3]{x})^2 + 4\sqrt[3]{x} + 4}{(\sqrt[3]{x})^3 + 8}
  = \frac{\sqrt[3]{x^2} + 4\sqrt[3]{x} + 4}{x + 8}
$$